# SQL select elements where sum per element is grater than N

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given that I've got a table with the following content:

```
# select * from presence;
  id | employee  | date     | hours_worked |
 ----+-----------+----------+--------------
   1 |       John| 1/1/2021 | 8
   2 |       John| 1/2/2021 | 16       
   3 |       John| 1/3/2021 | 8       
   4 |       John| 1/4/2021 | 8
   5 |    Michael| 1/1/2021 | 8
   6 |    Michael| 1/2/2021 | 8
   7 |    Michael| 1/3/2021 | 8
   8 |    Michael| 1/4/2021 | 8
   9 |    Michael| 1/5/2021 | 8
  10 |    Michael| 1/6/2021 | 8
  11 |    Michael| 1/7/2021 | 12

 (11 rows)
```

I would like to select N employee, which sum of hours worked is greater than Y (for testing  let's say it is  24, then correct results will be

```
  id | employee  | date     | hours_worked |
 ----+-----------+----------+--------------
     
   3 |       John| 1/3/2021 | 8       
   4 |       John| 1/4/2021 | 8
   9 |    Michael| 1/5/2021 | 8
  10 |    Michael| 1/6/2021 | 8
  11 |    Michael| 1/7/2021 | 12
```

I don't figure out how could I keep a partial sum for every employee and do a partial sum to select only what  it's above threshold Y(24 in this case).

Comment: John reach 24 hours worked on 1/2/2021 then on date 1/3/2021 and 1/4/2021 is above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cumulative `SUM`, and then filter on that value:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,
           employee,
           [date],
           hours_worked,
           SUM(hours_worked) OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY [date]
                                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total_hours_worked
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT id,
       employee,
       [date],
       hours_worked
FROM CTE
WHERE total_hours_worked > 24;
```

Comment: You're welcome, @xinta . If it answers the question, please do mark it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it.
If this won't work it will still be a great start to look at.

```
WITH employeeHourCount AS
(
    SELECT employee, SUM(hours_worked) as HoursWorked
    FROM presence
    GROUP BY employee
)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    presence
WHERE
    employee IN 
                (
                    SELECT employee
                    FROM employeeHourCount
                    WHERE HoursWorked > 24
                )
```